# JSON syntax error occure when jsone_decode in php but json data actually not contain any syntax error

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am trying to get post details using **JSON** in wordpress. In my plugin following is the `json_decode` part. But it returns `null`.

```
$post_count = intval($instance['post_count']);
$eng_posts= @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://athavaneng.com/?page_id=206861&posts_per_page=".$post_count), true);
switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
```

In the above code I get a `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` error. But actually when I test the returning JSON data of http://athavaneng.com/?page_id=206861 URL on the http://jsonlint.com. It says that "**Valid JSON**".

Why is that? What is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't pull out your packet sniffer to figure out what PHP is requesting and what the response actually is.

Comment: checking your URL with jsonlint (not pasting the json directly) gives JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Please tell me how to solve that issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responding server is sending 3 strange chars before it starts the json output. By doing this:

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://athavaneng.com/?page_id=206861&posts_per_page=1");

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {    
    echo $var[$i] . " : " . ord($var[$i]) . "<br />";    
}
```

you will get something like this:

```
ï : 239
» : 187
¿ : 191
{ : 123
" : 34
1 : 49
" : 34
: : 58
{ : 123
" : 34
```

the first three chars (239,187 and 191) should not been printed by the server. As a workaround you should be able to parse it after stripping the first three chars.

I am able to parse your json with the following code, which beginns reading at character 3:

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://athavaneng.com/?page_id=206861&posts_per_page=1", false, NULL, 3);
var_export(json_decode($var));
```

Comment: Hi steven. You are best. Thank you for the answer and it is working excellent. I am sad that not able to vote up because of I havent enough reputations. Thank you so much Steven.